# Handling filenames in ubuntu not working!

Tags: 19.10, filename

I am trying to manage a Windows file named “- – file.txt” from the Linux command prompt but using “./- – file.txt” or “– – – file.txt” does not work

any suggestions?

I tried googling but no good.

Comment: You're trying to *manage*? What do you mean by manage? And what do you believe `---file.txt`  should do?

Comment: Are you sure you are typing the correct file name?